# Jquery tab not updating CSS properly when adding new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I am trying to create a new tab that will allow for you to see content in the tab and choose between the tabs, Currently when i add a new tab it does not allow me to switch between tabs and breaks the other tab. I have found this to be due to the CSS not refreshing and loading inside the new tab div. What do i need to do to ensure that the new div has the css for the Tab.

```
function addGroup() {
tabcount++;
document.getElementById('tab').innerHTML += '<li><a href="#tabs-'+tabcount+'">Aenean lacinia</a></li>';
document.getElementById('tab-content').innerHTML += '<div id="tabs-'+tabcount+'"><h2>Content heading 3</h2><p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p></div>';
```

Im using Jquery 1.11 aswell and tried looking at their documentation but did not notice documentation on how to add tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving different ids to different tabs here

```
id="tabs-'+tabcount+'"
```

So I guess you will have tabs like `tabs-0` `tabs-1`. The style you apply to `tabs-0` will not apply to `tabs-1`.

You can either add class to the divs and then target those classes using css selectors

```
<div id="tabs-'+tabcount+'" class="tabs">
```

with

```
.tabs {
    //css code
}
```

OR add the css for every id you use

```
#tabs-1, #tabs-2 {
    //css code
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the problem, which i should have been more clear about, is that the Jquery tabs automatically import class, role and several other tags in the <li> and <div> tags. How do i refresh or use Jquery to add those existing CSS tags to work in unison with exisiting tabs